# Will jrockit upgrade requires nodemanager to re-enroll with Weblogic domain

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic11g, wlst, jrockit

I have upgraded jrockit to version 28.3.11. After that nodemanager becomes inactive when checked in Weblogic Admin console. I restarted the node manager, but it didn't resolved the issue. I got below error message in node manager log.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:944)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:880)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
>       at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
>       at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
>       at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
>       at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
>       at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.run(Handler.java:71)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682) Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
>       ... 11 more
>
> weblogic.nodemanager.common.ConfigException: The
>   domain 'mydomain' at 'null' was not registered in the
>   nodemanager.domains file and dynamic domain registration is not
>   supported. Please register the domain in the nodemanager.domains file.
>       at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.getDomainManager(NMServer.java:274)
>       at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.handleDomain(Handler.java:227)
>       at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.handleCommand(Handler.java:109)
>       at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.run(Handler.java:71)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)

I restarted Node manager, but not resolving the issue.

Any suggestion would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are working on old version of WebLogic. You log shows:

```
Please register the domain in the nodemanager.domains file.
```

Did you tried to connect with WLST and register with nmEnroll() command. Also check the nodemanager.domains file content in the $NM_HOME [where nodemanager.properties exists].

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the commment. I was using WL version 12.1.1.0.7 and jrockit version R28.2.9. Now I updated WL and jrockit to 12.1.1.0.12 and 28.3.11 respectively. Before upgrade, nodemanager were working fine. But after jrockit upgrade, nodmanager becomes inative. So should it required to re-enroll the nodemanager after WL and jrcokit upgrade?